# Using a Jpeg to Mask another Image with pure CSS?

Tags: css, jpeg, mask

I need to use the black pixels of a Jpeg image as a "transparency layer" to mask another image.

When I use this PNG image as a mask, it works fine:

(it's a white square in an alpha background)

[image]

But I need to do the same with a Jpeg image, replacing the alphachannel with black ! (so without alpha channel).

Here's my CSS:

```
#selection-image {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-mask-image: urlhttps://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/14/4/1554391365-output-onlinepngtools-2.png);
  -webkit-mask-size: 1000px 800px;
  mask-image: url(https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/14/4/1554391365-output-onlinepngtools-2.png);
  mask-size: 1000px 800px;
  mask-type: alpha;
  background: red;
}
```

I cannot use canvas to delete the black pixel, as it takes too much time. I thought I could use the property mask-type: luminance, but it seems to work only with alpha channel too ..

Comment: why is it even necessary to do this in pure css and not with just an image that does/looks like what you need it to in the first place?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Because this mask image is generated by an external application and sent as base64, compressed in jpeg. For some reasons, I cannot use png format ...